# Prove that a group of order 5 doesnt have any self-inverse member other than the identity member.

Tags: group-theory

Assuming you only know the most basic ideas about groups properties-

If group G contains 5 members, how do you prove that no member other than the identity member is self inverse?

*I rather have a clue on how to begin solving it or how to approach this problem than have the whole proof :)

Comment: Easiest way: just show it explicitly

Comment: you mean with a table?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Such an element would have order $2$, but the order of an element divides the order of the group

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: you might like to post that as an answer.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner for now, we assume I have no idea what is an order of an element

Comment: Okay, I posted an answer with a definition of the order of an element

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "most basic", e.g. does this include kowledge of basic results about order,  or Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: any group of order $5$ is isomorphic to integers modulo $5$ under addition, but if $x\equiv -x\pmod5$ then $2x\equiv0\pmod5$ so $x\equiv0\pmod5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to complete the operation table.  Let the elements be $a,b,c,d,e$ with $e$ the identity and $aa=e$.  Now $ab$ has to be something, so it might as well be $c$.  What is $ac?$  Keep going until you find a contradiction.

Comment: so this is exactly how I did it, I just feel its tedious and I would like to know if theres an elegant way to prove it

Comment: You said you just had basic ideas about group properties, so I didn't use any theorems.  If you know Lagrange's theorem you can just say that $\{a,e\}$ forms a subgroup, but the order of subgroups has to divide the order of the group.  I don't think this is so tedious here.  You have $ac=aab=b$, then $ad=d$ is a contradiction

Comment: alright thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

From [Lagrange's theorem,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory))
the  order of any element $a$ of a finite group (i.e. the smallest positive integer   $k$ with $a^k = e,$ where $e$ is the identity element of the group) divides the order of that group.  If $a$ is self-inverse and $a\ne e$, then the order of $a$ is $2$.  $2$ does not divide $5$, so there cannot be such $a$.

Comment: But does "most basic ideas" include Lagrange? Obviously it is trivial if one knows that and the question probably would not have been asked if so.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $a=a^{-1}$ and $a \neq e$. $G$ can be partioned in two disjoint sets: put $S = \{x \in G: x=x^{-1}\}$ and $T=\{x \in G: x \neq x^{-1}\}$, then $G = S \cup T$ and since $a, e \in S$, $|S| \geq 2$.

Note that $|T|$ is even (elements of $T$ come in pairs), which leaves us with $|T|=0$ or $2$ (if its cardinality would be equal to $4$ then $5 \geq 2+4$, which is absurd).

If $T$ is empty then *every* element of $G$ equals its inverse. Next to $e$ and $a$, let $b$ a third element of $G$ different from $e$ and $a$. Then clearly, $ab \in G$ and $ab \notin \{e,a,b\}$. Note that $ab=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba$. So $G=\{e,a,b,ab,c\}$ for some $c$ not equal to any of the other elements. Since $ac \in G$ we now reach a contradiction: go verify that $ac \neq e, ac \neq a, ac \neq b, ac \neq ab, ac \neq c$.

If $|T|=2$, then $S=\{1,a,b\}$ and $T=\{c, c^{-1}\}$, for certain $b,c \in G, a \neq b \neq e$. Since $G$ is closed, $ab \in G$ and it is trivial to see that $ab \notin \{e,a,b\}$. Hence (after appropriate renaming) we can assume $ab=c$ and thus $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba=c^{-1}$.

So after all, $G=\{e,a,b,ab, ba\}$. Now for the final contradiction, we must have that $bab \in G$, but go verify it is not equal to any of the elements of $G$ (for example, if $bab=e$, then $ba=b^{-1}=b$, whence $a=e$, etc..)

Comment: (+1) I like this perspective; that is, that of using the even cardinality of $T$. It's neat.